# Colour entire row when date in shell matches today's date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function colorEntireRowGreenWhenDateOfEventMatchesCurrentDate() {

  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dateColumn = data.getRange("C2:C15").getValues();
  var todaysDate = new Date();
  Logger.log(data)

  for (i=0; i=dateColumn.length; i++) {
    if (dateColumn[i] = todaysDate) {
      data.setTabColor("#3c643c");
    }
  }
}
```

Simply easy request. I want to colour an entire row green when the date entry in column C matches the today's date.

Comment: What is the problem with your piece of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple problem on your code.

First, you made a mistake on your date comparaison

```
 if (dateColumn[i] = todaysDate) {
```

instead of

```
 if (dateColumn[i] == todaysDate) {
```

Also, the best way to compare date is to compare the time by using [getTime() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp). See also this SO question : [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

You try to use the [Sheet.setTabColor(String) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setTabColor(String)) which modify the tab color of the sheet, when you try to get the [Range.setBackground(String) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) or the [Range.setBackgroundRGB(red, green, blue) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundrgbred-green-blue).

Here is a solution:

```
function colorEntireRowGreenWhenDateOfEventMatchesCurrentDate() {

  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = data.getRange("C2:C15");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  var todaysDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
  Logger.log(data);
  range.setBackground(null);

  for (var i in values) {
    var d = values[i][0];
    if (d.getTime() === todaysDate.getTime()) {
      var row = parseInt(i) + 1;
      data.getRange(range.getCell(row, 1).getRow(),1,1,data.getMaxColumns()).setBackground('#3c643c');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an 'TypeError: Cannot find function getTime in object . (line 14, file "Code")' error when debugging the code, I think is because 'd' in not a date object.

Comment: You need to use date format on your spreadsheet, otherwise, it can't do the comparaison between the day date and the spreadsheet date.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) explains how to set background color for cells. You can either use [setBackground](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) or [setBackgroundRGB](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundrgbred-green-blue)

Comment: Answers work better with an explanation on why they should work.

Comment: @apokryfos Sure, I'm adding a reference

Answer (score 0):

This can be done much more simply with conditional formatting. Use custom formula in A2.

```
=$C2:$C=today()
```

Set range A2:F (change F to your last data column.